# Include .R Files in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, file, include, shinydashboard

I am now the only responsible for the R shiny Dashboard at work and have got a question.

I know that the ui.R , global.R and Server.R are started automatically from the Server. Now I can see a production.R file, with a function "doSomething()" used in the Server.R file, but the production.R file isn't included or called.

If I move an .R file into the Server Directory, would I be able to access to its functions and variables automatically? In my eyes it has to be so, because everything works fine and the function from the production.R is really used.

Greetings an thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every .R file in the same directory as the ui.R and server.R should be called when running Shiny.
You might have to source the file in your server.R script.